# Can't understand function call and return-type

Tags: c, function, return-value

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* left;
    struct node* right;
};

struct node* createNode(value){
    struct node* newNode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newNode->data = value;
    newNode->left = NULL;
    newNode->right = NULL;
    return newNode;
}

struct node* insertLeft(struct node *root, int value) {
    root->left = createNode(value);
    return root->left;
}

struct node* insertRight(struct node *root, int value){
    root->right = createNode(value);
    return root->right;
}

int main(void) {
    struct node *root = createNode(1);           
    insertLeft(root, 2);  
    insertRight(root, 3);
    printf("The elements of tree are %d %d %d",
            root->data, root->left->data, root->right->data);
}
```

In the above code for a tree implementation, I am not able to understand the 
`insertLeft(root,2)` or `inserRight(root,3)` function calls.
Why is that we have added a return-type `struct node*` in the function definition and have written 
`return root->left;`.

I mean, why is it not showing any error when we compile because I think when the function is being called, it should be written like:-

```
a = insertLeft(root,2);
```

instead of only:-

```
insertLeft(root,2);
```

Please clarify as it is a basic concept of functions but I am not able to understand why the above code is running without any warning or error?

Since I am not able to get a satisfactory answer for my query, I am adding below a code to find whether the number entered by the user is prime or not, in order to show what I am actually asking in the code above..please have a look:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int getInteger(); //function declaration
int main()
{
    int n, i, flag = 0;
    n = getInteger();   // no argument is passed 
    for(i=2; i<=n/2; ++i)
    {
        if(n%i==0){
            flag = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (flag == 1)
        printf("%d is not a prime number.", n);
    else
        printf("%d is a prime number.", n);
    return 0;
}
int getInteger(){  //function definition
    int n;
    printf("Enter a positive integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    return n;
}
```

See, in the above code return type is **int**, therefore while calling the function the value returned from function definition is stored in **n** as I have written

```
n=getInteger();
```

Similary, in the first code written, it should have been like **a=insertLeft(root,2)** because we are using a return-type **struct node*** same as int in the above code for prime numbers.

Comment: You don't have to use return values from functions.

Comment: There is no error or warning needed, because you don't have to use the return value.

Comment: @user3981 This declaration  struct node* createNode(value){ is invalid. The type of the parameter is absent.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow but it's not showing up any error even if the type of parameter is absent.

Comment: @KenWhite ok if i remove the return values from function definition, then code runs fine, but my question is if we have a return-type like here struct node* in a function, then isn't it necessary to return a value in function definition??

Comment: @user3981 It looks like a compiler bug.

Comment: Sometimes the return value is the same as what was passed as an argument, for convenience in making compound statements. For example `strcat` *returns the destination string. No return value is reserved to indicate an error*, but that may not always be the case.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i am using devc++ compiler.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow — that's a K&R (pre-standard) C function with 'implicit `int`' as the type for `value`.  It hasn't been legal in Standard C for the whole of this millennium (it was outlawed in C99), but there are (too many) compilers that haven't heard about the change of millennium yet

Comment: @user3981 If an identifier list is present then each identifier shall be declared.  So it is a compiler bug.

Comment: Compare with eg `int printf(const char *fmt, ...);` which you use all the time ignoring the value it returns.

Comment: @ryyker The IDE he is using is not relevant to the question, which is about the language itself, not the IDE.

Comment: @GovindParmar - Yes, I can see that.  I may have put too much weight on some of the comments about compiler bugs, thus making the connection to the _buggy IDE, shipped with very old version of GCC_ content in the tag notes.  Point taken.  Thanks.

Comment: Some style guide forbid to ignore returned values, and some static code analyzers on request mark this as an error. To make it visible that you want to ignore the returned value, you commonly write `(void)function_returning_a_value();`. It does not hurt to use this even in other cases.

Comment: In your special case the author might have thought of some case of application when the returned value can be used. For example, you might like to investigate the freshly created node without having to traverse the tree.